# Refactoring dirty code asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-services, c#-4.0, refactoring

Sorry for my english.

I'm on a bad and old project. I try to refactoring several part of the code.

I've a big class which call methods of a WebService in many static methods (very dirty). 
The piecularity of theses methods is that before each call to a webservice method, an other webservice method is always called (This call is obligaroty and I can't modify the WebService)

I search a means to encapsulate this first call to avoid the code redundancy and facilitate future developments

These methods are similar to :

```
public static ObjectResult MethodeA(int methodParam1, string methodParam2, ...)
{
    MyWebService ws = new MyWebService();

    ObjectResult result = null;

    try
    {
        string aParam1 = GetParam1();

        ws.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        ObjectResultContext myContext = ws.GetUserContext(aParam1); // This method is always called before any webservice method call

        if (myContext.IsOK)
        {
            ws.UserProperties = myContext.UserProperties;
            result = ws.GetResultMethodA(methodParam1, methodeParam2);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ...
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       //...
        throw;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about refactoring/improving working code belong on Code Review, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would load the userProperties just **once** at the class constructor so you can remove it from the static webservice call:

You could do it like this:

```
public WebServiceClass
{
  private UserProperties userproperties;

  public WebServiceClass
  {
      ObjectResultContext myContext = ws.GetUserContext(aParam1); 
       if (myContext.IsOK)
        {
            userproperties = myContext.UserProperties;           
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ...
        }

  }

  public static ObjectResult MethodeA(int methodParam1, string methodParam2, ...)
  {
      MyWebService ws = new MyWebService();

      ObjectResult result = null;

      try
      {
          string aParam1 = GetParam1();

          ws.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;


          ws.UserProperties = myContext.UserProperties;
          result = ws.GetResultMethodA(methodParam1, methodeParam2);

      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         //...
          throw;
      }

      return result;
  }

}
```

Comment: I don't know why I don't think this... Simple but answer to the problem